# Error: exited with null when starting shared process on latest release version

Tags: visual-studio-code, digital-ocean, tmux, ubuntu-18.04

- `code-server` version: 1.408-vsc1.32.0
- OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04 x64 , DigitalOcean

### Description

I cannot run the command `code-server myApp`. It throws this error

[image]

*I followed two tutorials*

- https://github.com/codercom/code-server/blob/master/doc/admin/install/digitalocean.md
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Emn2YQNDl0

### Steps to Reproduce

1. `wget https://github.com/codercom/code-server/releases/download/1.408-vsc1.32.0/code-server1.408-vsc1.32.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`
2. `tar -xvzf code-server1.408-vsc1.32.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`
3. `cd code-server1.408-vsc1.32.0-linux-x64/`
4. `sudo chmod +x code-server`
5. `sudo mv code-server /bin/`
6. `cd ~/`
7. `code-server myApp`
8. Error Appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of RAM for a server to run this has to be about 2GB minimum.